# Simple-Salesforce API Version

Tags: python, salesforce, simple-salesforce

I am currently using the Version 1.11.1 library from (https://pypi.org/project/simple-salesforce/) to pull data from Salesforce. I noticed that it provides the ability to use Bulk API functions provided by Salesforce. Is this using the BULK API or the BULK API 2.0 version() in the background? I tried to look into the documentation and could not figure that out. Can somebody please point to a place in the documentation(or Github) where I could find this information?

Comment: If you want to use Salesforce with Airflow use Salesforce provider http://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-salesforce/stable/

Comment: I am already using this in Airflow.

Comment: So what is your Airflow question?

Comment: My question is - Simple Salesforce provides Bulk operations, such as             query = 'SELECT Id, Name FROM Account LIMIT 10'

sf.bulk.Account.query(query) , does this use the Bulk API 2.0 version to make Bulk Api  calls? (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_intro.htm)

Comment: I removed the airflow tag because this is not airflow question.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [open issue](https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce/issues/299) it looks like `simple-salesforce` currently does not support the BULK API 2.0.

One of the commenters recommended [`sfbulk2`](https://pypi.org/project/sfbulk2/) if you need to use Salesforce's BULK API 2.0.